# In Tkinter, how do I make it so that if I click a button, the condition is met and so the if statment happens?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I want it to check if the button is pressed, and then it does the if statement.

```
while x == 1:
    buttongbploop.pack()
    buttonaedloop.pack()
    buttonusdloop.pack()
    if invoke(buttonusdloop):
        print(tk, text="How many pounds?")
```

Comment: I assume there's other code around this? Could you give a [mcve]?

Comment: Having an infinite loop in a Tkinter program is almost always the wrong approach, since it causes the window to freeze indefinitely. Use `Tk.after` to perform periodic actions, and use the `command` named argument in the Button initializer to specify onclick behavior.

Comment: I tried to make a minimal example, however the same problem did not arise. All I can do is check through my code and see where the invalid syntax is.

Comment: @julianpopovskijones: yes, that's the whole point of making the minimal example: it helps you find the differences between your broken code and working code.